# Activity unit testing

Tags: android, unit-testing

I have an activity which preforms some work in the background and based on the result of this work starts one of two other activities. How can I write a unit test to validate its behavior?

I tried to use ActivityUnitTestCase but it blows up on an attempt to show a progress dialog. With ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 I could not find any way to intercept activity destruction. Any word of advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` is the correct approach as the other class is deprecated. To test what has happened after your main Activity, let's call it the `ProgressActivity`, you should use an [ActivityMonitor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor.html). I think you want to intercept the `Activity` creation, not the destruction.

I'm assuming here that ProgressActivity starts another `Activity` (let's say `A1`, `A2`, or `A3`) after some calculation is done in the background.

Your test case should be something like this:

```
public static final HashSet<Class<? extends Activity>> TARGET_ACTIVITIES = new HashSet<Class<? extends Activity>>();
static {
    TARGET_ACTIVITIES.add(A1.class);
    TARGET_ACTIVITIES.add(A2.class);
    TARGET_ACTIVITIES.add(A3.class);
}

private static final int TIMEOUT = 7000;

public void testRandomActivityStarted() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    ProgressActivity activity = getActivity();
    final Instrumentation inst = getInstrumentation();
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intentFilter.addCategory("MY_CATEGORY");
    ActivityMonitor monitor = inst.addMonitor(intentFilter, null, false);
    // Wait, before the Activity started
    monitor.waitForActivityWithTimeout(TIMEOUT);
    assertEquals(1, monitor.getHits());
    Activity randomActivity = monitor.getLastActivity();
    Log.d(TAG, "monitor=" + monitor + "   activity=" + randomActivity);
    // Unfortunately, it seems randomActivity is always null even after a match
    if ( randomActivity != null ) {
        assertTrue(TARGET_ACTIVITIES.contains(randomActivity.getClass()));
    }
    inst.removeMonitor(monitor);
}
```

The trick here is to use a category in the `IntentFilter`, because if you rely on `getLastActivity()` you may be disappointed as it seems it's always null. To be able to match this category you should use it when you start `A1`, `A2` or `A3` ([Intent.addCatrgory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#addCategory%28java.lang.String%29))

This example was adapted from the one that illustrates [ActivityMonitor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor.html) in [Android Application Testing Guide](http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/2011/06/android-application-testing-guide.html).

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. There are a few problems with the code sample as suggested. First, the monitor has to be set up BEFORE the call to getActivity. More importantly, waitForActivity returns the activity it was hit with and RESETS it to null. This is why the getLastActivity returns null. So instead of relaying on getActivity we need to use the value returned by wait...

Comment: If you set up the monitor BEFORE getActivity you may get 2 hits and the test may fail, but of course this depends on specific details of the activities involved. Regarding getLastActivity you are right, it's better to use the value returned by waitForActivity.

Comment: Another thing - I removed the category and it still works fine. So apparently there is no need for using category here

Comment: Well, it depends... if you want to get the hits on the monitor and you want to impose some kind of filtering you would need the category, otherwise any activity will match.